# How to achieve same print functionality of Silverlight into WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, printing

We are migrating our SilverLight application into WPF, in our application for printing we have used System.Windows.Printing. Same namespace is not available in WPF it has System.Drawing.Printing namespace, due to this existing functionality is not working as expected. We need to write the new printing for this. Is there any way we can achieve the same without writing new code.

Comment: Here's the MSDN [Printing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/printing-overview) for WPF. WPF printing uses the `System.Printing` namespace. `System.Drawing.Printing` is for WinForms.

Comment: Thanks, I already used it but some functionality is not present in that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify what functionality you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of printing a file with a choice of printer in WPF

```
    private static void PrintFile(string pathToFile)
    {
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        bool? print = pDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (print == true)
        {
            string printerName = pDialog.PrintQueue.FullName;
            Process p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    Verb = "PrintTo",
                    FileName = pathToFile
                }
            };
            p.Start();
        }
    }
```